# Will an English CAPTCHA be an issue for people in other countries?

Tags: security, internationalization, captcha

What if I have a captcha that displays a series of English characters.   Will people who don't speak English have trouble interpreting and/or typing these characters?  If this is the case then what is the best solution for an internationalized captcha?

Comment: For western countries this should be no problem since they use the latin alphabet too. Not sure how well people in some Asian countries can read the latin alphabet. Typing should be no problem, but being less used to these characters might reduce the recognition rate a bit.

Comment: In China, people write [pinjin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABny%C4%ABn) on QWERT-layout keyboards by default. But, why a CAPTCHA?

Comment: Use a captcha challenge having only numerals

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since 99% of the URLs are in regular ASCII, I don't think you will have a problem..after all how would they get to Google or Yahoo if they couldn't type the URL

That said I have on occasion run across Chinese characters used in captchas

Comment: I don't quite understand what URLs have to do with it. Being able to enter the word is one thing, being able to understand it is another. BTW. Could you please tell me the source of your statistic? Or is it just rough guess?

Comment: @Pawel Understanding the word isn't very important in a captcha. It's just an error correction mechanism that increases the recognition rate.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Understanding the word is a difference between being able to recognize a character (i.e. is it o or a). Don't tell me it is not an issue, I have such problems too many times.

Answer (score 6):

Image-based CAPTCHA has two main advantages over text-based CAPTCHA:

1. International
2. Harder to solve algorithmically (see [PWNtcha - captcha decoder](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha))

There are several flavors, such as:

1. Classification: see [Captcha The Dog](http://www.captchathedog.com/),  [KittenAuth](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2006/04/6554.ars), [Microsoft Asirra](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/)
2. 3D projection: see [3D images: A human way to create Captchas](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-10198703-1.html) and [3D-based Captchas become reality](http://www.cnet.com/8301-17914_1-10204300-89.html)
3. Detection: see [Image-Based CAPTCHA from Confident Technologies](http://drupal.org/project/confident_captcha) and [Pic-Capture](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=195186)
4. Rotation: see [A Dynamic, User-Friendly Captcha With Pictures](http://blog.plantwars.com/index.php/2009/09/07/a-dynamic-user-friendly-captcha-with-pictures)
5. Puzzle: see [Key Captcha](https://www.keycaptcha.com/)

Answer (score 3):

It would be a problem for users using their native, non-Latin keyboard layout, for example Russians and Greeks. They would be forced to switch keyboard layout just to fill security question.

Another thing is an ability to even recognize the words - somebody who doesn't speak English could have huge problems with getting word right. Even I sometimes do (for less popular words), although I am quite proficient...

In other words, don't do this mistake, your application should be easy to use for all users.

Comment: wouldn't they also have to switch the layout to just visit my site because the domain name is in English?  Also this really isn't a solution.

Comment: @Rook: How often do you type a domain name on the address bar? Unless your site is very popular, users will often search for something and then click on a link. If they like your site, it is likely that they will bookmark it. Again, no layout switching.
As for solution, there are some possibilities: 1. Avoid using captchas. 2. Using localized captchas. 3. Using some math equation as a captcha and force users to enter the number (not sure if it helps). 4. Using several images (with defined alt tag) and translatable sentence with a definition of one of them - users would click the right one.

Comment: @Rook: For the last one, it should be different. No alt tags unless somebody click "visually impaired". But in this case it should use sounds instead of written definitions, i.e. (text) what item could make this sound, (sound) buzz, (texts as images are useless) bell, guitar, ..., buzzer :)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a concern. Dictionary-based CAPTCHAs should ideally adapt to the user's language preferences and ask them to recognize words that match their language preferences and by extension the character set they are most familiar with.

But in the absence of such internationalization, I would say that numerals and mathematical expressions are the most universal solution, and for word-based CAPTCHAs a random series of ASCII characters (which being random would be culture-neutral) would be the most accessible as pretty much any user around the world has the ability to enter these characters even if some have to switch their input method.

Now where it really gets tricky is providing accessibility alternatives for visually impaired users. Making a univeral audio CAPTCHA seems pretty much impossible (you could consider a set of universally-recognized sounds instead of spoken words, but I doubt this would provide sufficient security). And internationalized (multilingual) spoken word generation is far from trivial.

Answer (score 1):

No, because English captchas are ASCII -- ASCII is always available, even if people have a Japanese, Chinese, or Russian keyboard. So this should not be a problem!  And image based captchas only require the person to read the letter - and that should be possible for anybody on the web who can see, as SQLMenace pointed out.

The other way around is a problem though.

Google's reCaptcha has a little icon where the user can get a different captcha if for some reason the captcha is not readable or contains foreign characters.

**I would recommend that you use Google's reCaptcha, rather than implementing it yourself.**

Added Benefit:

**Google's reCaptcha** is also available for other languages btw. http://www.google.com/recaptcha/faq
which **makes it possible for you to internationalize the captcha for the user's default locale**.

---

EDIT:

There is a work-around for Google's reCaptcha to work with flash!

Check here:
http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/e22d7e3c91bcc9db

Comment: +1 Sure I'd love to use reCaptcha,  but it can't be used on flash.  So i must roll my own,  no solution,  no award sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sure they are a problem. Would a Russian captcha be a problem for you? What about a Chinese one?

The URLs are indeed ASCII, but that is only relevant for geeks.
Regular people go to Google, type some text in their own language, and then click on one of the answers. Then never get to type an URL.

Comment: I'd imagine Russians/Chinese are far more used to typing ASCII characters than vice versa. After all, you couldn't get an internationalized URL until recently. You say "regular people go to Google", but you often go to Google by **typing Google.com in ASCII**.

Comment: If you would get in touch with people that are not geeks, like you and me, you would know that they don't type URLs, not even the Google one. They just start the browser, and the home page is usually some kind of search engine. Either the default browser one, or whatever the nephew/isp/mall-ware configured for them. See also Paweł's comment above: "How often do you type a domain name on the address bar?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could represent a problem to a small percentage of users. Is it a large enough problem to take into consideration when building the UI for your site to better the UX? That's up to you. If it were up to me, probably not.

To help you in the right direction though, I would use Google' reCAPTCHA. It serves a great cause and works like a charm. There's also a great API where you can customize the language that it displays. You could use PHP to detect their country and write some code to change the settings to display in their native language.

Here's a sample of changing reCATCHA's language. "fr" is french!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   lang : 'fr',
};
</script>
```

Google reCATPCHA's API:

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html#i18n

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the 24 letters that constitute the English alphabet correspond in most 90% of the world. We have Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic and Arabic users however all of them have the possibility of switching to an English keyboard within their operating systems.

We have no diacritics in English which makes everything a lot easier and our system more easily adaptable all over the world. Everyone types ASCII but they are able to switch to their own zone-specific/language-specific characters.